# Database table prefix in controller file of CAKEPHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Any short code to get the database table prefix in cakephp controller action ?

Please advise me .Thanks in advance

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? Database table prefix is defined in `/app/Core/database.php`, is this what you want?

Comment: No I wanna just print the table prefix in controller action for some reason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well:

```
$prefix = $this->ModelName->tablePrefix;
```

Comment: it is also documented: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#tableprefix